# Build/run qBittorrent through Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm looking to work on the qBittorrent code to see if I can help out with it. I'm a C# developer but I did C/C++ 15 years ago so I'm not up to speed on the current state of C++ development. The wiki they have on the qBittorrent website only covers building the app, but I want to use Visual Studio 2017/2019 to code and test it. It doesn't have a vcxproj file, so does anyone know how to set it up in Visual Studio 2017 or 2019? I can probably figure out the 3rd party libraries (Qt, zlib, etc) on my own but totally clueless on how to setup just the qBittorrent code in Visual Studio.

Comment: Looks like you can use `CMake` to generate a Visual Studio project file. https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent

Comment: There also is the option of the Qt addon to Visual Studio or `QMake` since there is a .pro file.